# Finding Average Wait Time From Number of People Waiting

Tags: estimation, mean, queueing

Problem:

We are trying to estimate the average wait time for a process. Only data we have is how many people are in the system at a given time, how many have entered this period, how many exited this period and the length of the queue at the end of the period.

Data example:

| Period | Waiting at the start of Period | New Applications | Finished Applications | Waiting end of period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 100 | 50 | 1050 |
| 2 | 1050 | 200 | 150 | 1100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Goal: to find the average time people who made their application in period x waited.

My Attempt: Using the general queue model (mm1), got the average waiting time as arrivals/ pending. This method assumes the serving times follow the same distribution over time, which is a fine assumption; however, we believe the number of servers in the queue changes over time (hence variable waiting time estimates).

How would we go about estimating the average wait time for a person entering the system at period X given we have only these observations? We believe this is a first come first serve queue if it is any help.

Comment: It depends on how the number of servers changes over time. Notate your variables: $p|l_p|a_p|f_p|p+1$. If you have no idea how the number of servers will change then your best guess ought to be $l_p/f_p$, this assumes the current rate is the best guess. Perhaps you think it will trend back toward the average service rate (notate it $s_p=\sum_{p=1}^nf_p/n$) later, so perhaps you would suppose that $f_p$ would be served this period, then $.8f_p + .2s_p$, then $.8(.8f_p + .2s_p)+.2s_p$ and so on. Ideally you would describe how the servers change over time and use that info.

Comment: Little's Law may be useful here

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst I was trying to use little's law. However, estimators based on LL are highly biased when the serving times are long (in the data at 3-6 period range) and the arrival times are time varying. How can we correct for the biases there? If not is there a better way to approach the situation other than LL?